# Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional) (3.0.0) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core (3.0.0)", or compatible

Tags: apache-flex, subclipse

Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional) (3.0.0) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core (3.0.0)", or compatible.

Error occured when I tried to update site in Flex. Can anyone say whats the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to deselect that plugin.  It is marked optional because all it does is provide some integration between Subclipse and Mylyn.  Based on the error, it sounds like you do not have Mylyn installed, so there is no need to install this integration plugin.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I did in this way and it works for me. Thanks Mark